# reCaptcha not displaying; producing JS error

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, recaptcha

I have a joomla site that I am trying to implement a reCaptcha for registration, forgot password, etc. None of them are showing though.

The code producing the error is:

```
window.setInterval(function () {
    var r;
    try {
        r = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    } catch (e) {}
    if (r) {
        r.open("GET", "./", true);
        r.send(null)
    }
}, 840000);
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.hasTooltip').tooltip({
        "html": true,
        "container": "body"
    });
});
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    Recaptcha.create("6LfQ_AETAAAAAI0fspPMohmBWrNynQUEHLg4rcUV", "jform_captcha", {
        theme: "clean",
        lang: 'en',
        tabindex: 0
    });
});
```

The error thrown is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
(anonymous function)
m.Callbacks.j
m.Callbacks.k.fireWith
m.extend.ready
J
```

Since this is a Joomla site and for the most part packaged its hard to include complete relevant code without flooding the post. Was hoping somebody else had dealt with this before.

Though taboo, for reference my URL throwing the error is http://inputmapper.com/component/users/?view=registration incase more context is needed.

Comment: `jQuery('.hasTooltip').tooltip({"html": true,"container": "body"});` is the line throwing the error FYI

Comment: Have you included jQueryUI in the page?

Comment: ^ You also have an eclectic mix of Mootools and jQuery on your site. You might want to pick one or the other to avoid issues.

Comment: Im not too familiar with jQ, but if you mean the jQ library, yes it is loaded by default by joomla.

Comment: @ReLeaf Can't really help that, Joomla has no 'standard' its all a little of this and a little of that.

Comment: Everything points me to the fact that it is the template, Thats what I get for using a canned template. I guess ill design one from scratch.